# How to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() or ProcessBuilder or anyother way to execute a complex/hybrid unix/linux command in java

Tags: java, linux, unix, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I have written a command

```
for i in `cat  ./files/logs1.txt | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | cut -c 1-3 | sort| uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 1d | head -n 10 | awk '{print $2}' `; do grep ^$i ./files/logs1.txt > $i.txt; done
```

which runs perfectly fine from terminal. But I need to run it using java. I have tried using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and ProcessBuilder but I am not sure how to break this command into a string array which would help me run this.

```
String myCommand = "for i in `cat  ./files/logs1.txt | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | cut -c 1-3 | sort| uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 1d | head -n 10 | awk '{print $2}' `; do grep ^$i ./files/logs1.txt > $i.txt; done";
    Process p = r.exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", myCommand });
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }


    br.close();
```

Comment: Your example code seems to work, when all needed stuff is added around it. So there is not functional need to break content of myCommand to a string array.